# Why custom constructor in Laravel command cause "Invalid argument supplied for foreach"?

Tags: php, model, laravel

I have created a command as follow:

```php
<?php
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
class SchedulesCommand extends Command {

    protected $name = "mod:check";

    protected $description = "Checks the Database for any upcoming schedules.";

    protected $mod;

    public function __construct (Model $mod){
        $this->mod = $mod;
    }

    public function fire(){
        $this->line('Checking the database');
        $this->mod->f1 = 1;
        $this->mod->f2 = "test";
        $this->mod->f3 = 'Command';
        $this->mod->save();
    }
?>
```

I get the following error - don't know why --

```php
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Invalid argument supplied for foreach()","file":"\/home\/test\/Documents\/account1\/PHP Scripts\/project\/vendor\/symfony\/console\/Symfony\/Component\/Console\/Application.php","line":409}}
```

Can someone tell me what might be going wrong?

This is my `artisan.php` file:

```php
 $mod = new Model;
 $artisan->add(new SchedulesCommand($mod));
```

Comment: Try adding: `parent::__construct();` in the first line of your constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should always calls the parent constructor when creating a Laravel Command.

In your constructor add `parent::__construct()` as the first line to look as follow:

```php
public function __construct (Model $mod)
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->mod = $mod;
}
```

Keep in mind that calling the parent constructor allow Laravel to configure the name, description, and parameters on the console command to make things a little easier for us.